# Jquery on off first click doesn't fire on first click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using MVC 5 and Razor front end.  When I click any button for the first time, it will not play. It will play on the second click.  I tried .off at the end of the code but it didnt work.  I want it to play for the first click on a button then turn off.  Right now it takes two clicks on a button to start the track and work correctly for the other tracks.

```
function play() {
//$(".song").unbind().click(function () {
$(".song").off('click').on('click', function () {

        //this is the url
        var url = $(this).attr("data-song");

    var audio = $("#myAudio")[0];

    if (audio.paused) {
        audio.src = url;
        audio.play();
    } else {
        audio.pause();
        audio.currentTime = 0;
    }


});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<table class="table" id="trackTable">
<tr>
    <th>

    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Genre)
    </th>

</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td class="songRow">
            <a href="#"  class="song" data-song="@Url.Content(item.Path)"  onclick="play()" ><img src="~/Images/playpause.png" alt="playpause" id="playbutton"   /></a>

        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$(".song").on('click', function () {
   $(this).off('click');

   // do the other stuff
}
```

This way your link can be clicked once, and then *click* event handler is removed.

Comment: Tried it and it will not play at all.

Answer (score 0):

In this u first used on click function instead of using off click

Comment: Still takes two clicks to play.